# Change Calculator - Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and I am learning it in high school, so, I did what I understood and tried a lot of things but nothing gives me the right answer.
Please help me out.

> Write and test a function that converts a dollar amount less than $5 and returns the change using the least number of coins.
>
> Your function: `change(d: float)-->list`
>
> The function has one parameter for the dollar amount (float) and calculates the least number of toonies (two dollar coins), loonies (one dollar coins), quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies that make up the amount entered. The resultant quantities of coins are returned in a list.
>
> Expectations:
> Your code does not use if statements.

```
def change(dollars):
    toonies = int(dollars // 2)
    loonies = int(dollars % dollars)
    quarters = int(25 // dollars)
    dimes = int(10 // dollars)
    nickels = int(5 // dollars)
    pennies = int(1 // dollars)
    return [toonies,loonies,quarters,dimes,nickels,pennies]

dollars = 4.96 #float(input())

print(change(dollars))

# expected result - 4.96 = [2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1]
# actual result - [2, 0, 5, 2, 0, 1]
```

Comment: What is the point of `dollars % dollars`?

Comment: Each time you find the number of denomination, you need to subtract those from the original `dollars` amount. And your formulas are wrong, you should be dividing `dollars // 2` to get the number of toonies.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to start from high value change and to go down as that would leave us with the least amount of coins.

```
def change(dollars):
  toonies = int(dollars // 2)
  loonies = int((dollars%2)// 1)
  quarters = int(((dollars%2)%1)// 0.25)
  dimes = int((((dollars%2)%1)%0.25)// 0.1)
  nickels = int(((((dollars%2)%1)%0.25)%0.05)// 0.1)
  pennies = int((((((dollars%2)%1)%0.25)%0.05)%0.01)// 0.01)
  return [toonies, loonies, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies]

dollars = 4.96

print(change(dollars))

#returns [2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1]
```

The way this code works is by dividing the highest coin value, starting with toonies (2 dollars) and working its way down by dividing the remainder with the next low value amount.

I am pretty sure there is a way much more efficient than this, try figuring it out!

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out, I was starting to get so frustrated because I was so confused about what I should try next. I am very grateful for your help. Thank you!